# parameters functions at top and after begin

Tags: sql-server

HI  DBSimon  helped me correct my work- can you all help me understand :

```
 create function test (@takesID as int)
returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
declare @Description_mm nvarchar(50);
SELECT  @Description_mm =  Description_mm
FROM   dbo.Win_Products
WHERE        (ID = @takesID);
return @Description_mm;
end
```

HELP: 
1. I understand we use create and use function to avoid repetation but can you explain the parameters - like next to function name ( @takes..) what is that for and how to determine what to put there. 
2. also why we declare again after begin-  what is that for and how do we know what to put, don't we have to set the value since we declared. Await your reply. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `@takesID` is a value that changes that is passed to the function - in this case, the ID of the product whose description you want to return.

The `declare` declares a variable for use within the function and is only within scope within the function.